# Responsive navigation formatting issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, sass

I would appreciate some help with my nav bar, it seems to work well with tablet and below, however the logo is very squashed on desktop until it is in mobile where it works fine - could someone point me in the right direction on the fix for this? The logo would be bigger but it is just a place holder for now (i have tested with other logos and it seems to give the same result).

Also if someone could give me any indication on how i would use the search logo when on click it opens a search field (without JS if possible! I have currently got it working with jQuery but could do without it!)

I also have added a big breakpoint (1024px) until it goes into mobile view as the nav items didn't fit at a small resize - does anyone have any advice on a better way of formatting the navigation to be cleaner?

A few questions here but hope it makes sense!

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Desktop image
[image: image description]

Smaller devices image
[image: image description]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".search-logo").on('click', function() {
    $(".search-bar").toggle();

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 1.2vmin;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.search-logo {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

.search-bar {
  display: none;
}

.search-icon {
  font-size: 25px !important; //Due to icon inheriting from external css
  cursor: pointer;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .header a.logo {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/javascript.js">
  </script>
</head>



<body>

  <div class="header">
    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <div class="header-right">
      <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
      <a href="#">OUR WORK</a>
      <a href="#">NEWS</a>
      <a href="#">CAREER</a>
      <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      <a>
        <button type="submit" class="search-logo"><i class="fa fa-search search-icon"></i></button>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" class="search-bar">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Art Direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Art_direction) is what it seems like you are after. However, this can get unwieldy fast.

In your case, you might simply use a flexbox with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to get the job done.